# TypeScript React <img /> onLoad event.target can't find naturalWidth naturalHeight

Tags: html, reactjs, image, typescript

[image]

```
return <img {...props} onLoad={event => {
  console.log(event.target.naturalWidth)
}}/>
```

I want to retrieve naturalWidth & naturalHeight in TypeScript React.

But got stuck, TypeScript can't find that property.

How do I retrieve naturalWidth & naturalHeight in TypeScript React?

Comment: You can use 
let image =  event.target as HTMLImageElement;
console.log(event.target.naturalWidth);
Inside the body of function onload.

Comment: @Ganeshchaitanya thanks, I think this is the only way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access `HTMLImageElement` through `event.currentTarget` (not `event.target`) so this should work:

```
return <img {...props} onLoad={event => {
  console.log(event.currentTarget.naturalWidth)
}}/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to use a type assertion:

```
const { width, height } = e.currentTarget as HTMLImageElement;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try innerWidth and innerHeight.

console.log(event.target.innerWidth)

Comment: But I want original width & height

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        var img = $("#sky");
        // Create dummy image to get real size
        $("<img>").attr("src", $(img).attr("src")).load(function(){
            var realWidth = this.width;
            var realHeight = this.height;
            alert("Original width=" + realWidth + ", " + "Original height=" + realHeight);
        });
    });   
}); Try this.

Comment: That's jQuery though, I want TypeScript React solution.